# Specify sorting row in jQuery DataTable

Tags: datatables

How can I specify, in which header row the sorting will be enabled? I have a jQuery DataTable with 3 header rows. The third row displays sums and should not have sorting functionality. If I disable sorting in the third row with columnDefs by using a specific class, I cannot sort in colums with sums at all. It seems, that jQuery DataTable enables sorting in the last header row by default. Is it possible to change this?

```
"columnDefs": [{ sortable: false, targets: [ "sorting_disabled" ]}]
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LV88z.jpg)

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r002w0fb/5/

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery DataTables it's not possible to select middle header row for sorting. There is [`orderCellsTop`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/orderCellsTop) option that allows to select either top or bottom row but not middle.

The best thing you can do is to show summary row in the table footer.

See [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/r002w0fb/9/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Summary row table in the footer is not optimal, but: Thanks!